How can this pseudo inverse be a linear transformation?
So I've come across this definition of pseudo-inverse of a linear transformation from the book Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel & Spence which states that:
Let $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ be finite-dimensional inner product space over the same field, and let $\text{T}: \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{W}$ be a linear transformation. Let $\text{L}: N(\text{T})^{\perp} \to R(\text{T})$ be the linear transformation defined by $\text{L}(x) = \text{T}(x)$ $\forall$ $x \in N(\text{T})^{\perp}$. The pseudo-inverse (or Moore-Penrose generalized inverse) of $\text{T}$, denoted by $\text{T}^{\dagger}$, is defined as the linear transformation from $\mathbf{W}$ to $\mathbf{V}$ such that
$
\text{T}^{\dagger}(y) =
\begin{cases}
\text{L}^{-1}(y) & \text{for } y \in R(\text{T}) \\
0 & \text{for } y \in R(\text{T})^{\perp}
\end{cases}
$
Now, how can $\text{T}^{\dagger}$ be a linear transformation if we have a sum of two vectors $y_1 + y_2$ where $y_1 \in R(\text{T})$ and $y_2 \in R(\text{T})^{\perp}$? How can we then show that $\text{T}^{\dagger}(y_1+y_2) = \text{T}^{\dagger}(y_1)+\text{T}^{\dagger}(y_2)$? We can't just say that either of these two vectors are zero since $\mathbf{W}$ is the direct sum of $R(\text{T})$ and it's orthogonal complement, not their union.

Decompose $y_1$ and $y_2$ into orthogonal components in $R(T)$ and $R(T)^\perp$ then apply $T^\dagger$

you are reading the displayed equation as if it were a description of the output of $T^\dagger$ for any $y$, but that's not what the text says.  "the linear transformation from W to V such that..." means that there's one and only one linear transformation with the given property and that linear transformation is called $T^\dagger$.

@MatthewTowers what you're saying doesn't make sense to me.

Recall that a linear transformation is completely determined by the values it assumes on a basis. Since $R(T)\oplus R(T)^\perp=W$, we can pick a basis for each and concatenate them to get a basis for $W$. Then the rule
$$T^\dagger(y)=\begin{cases}
L^{-1}(y),&y\in R(t)\\
0,&y\in R(t)^\perp\end{cases}$$
allows us to determine the values of $T^\dagger$ on our basis of $W$. From there, we use linearity to find the values on arbitrary vectors. For instance, in your example, $y_2\in R(t)^\perp$ so $T^\dagger(y_1+y_2)=T^\dagger (y_1)=L^{-1}(y_1)$.

I don't really get it.

In general, if we have a linear transformation $S:V\to W$ and a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $V$, then $S$ is completely determined by the values $S(v_1),\ldots,S(v_n)$. This is because any $v\in V$ can be written in terms of our basis as $v=a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n$. Then we use linearity to see that $S(v)=a_1S(v_1)+\ldots+a_nS(v_n)$.

@MintoP Therefore, if we want to specify this transformation $T^\dagger$, all we need to specify is its values on some basis of $W$. We can pick a basis of $W$ so that every basis vector is either in $R(t)$ or $R(t)^\perp$, and then we use the rule above to figure out the values of $T^\dagger$ on this basis.

@MintoP By your assumption, $y_1\in R(t)$ and $y_2\in R(t)^\perp$. By linearity, $T^\dagger(y_1+y_2)=T^\dagger(y_1)+T^\dagger(y_2)$. But since $y_2\in R(t)^\perp$, $T^\dagger(y_2)=0$.

I still don't get it. My point is to show that $T^{\dagger}$ is a linear transformation. Not that it already is one. You're just assuming that $T^{\dagger}$ is LT because the question says so. If I have two vectors from $R(T)$ and $R(T)^{\perp}$ how can I be sure that their sum preserve linearity?

Even if we consider the bases for $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ and we'll still have two vectors from those bases and whether or not their addition would preserve linearity under $\text{T}^{\dagger}$.

@MintoP You do not have to show that $T^\dagger$ is linear. There is exactly one linear transformation which satisfies the above formula on $R(T)$ and $R(T)^\perp$. The book is defining $T^\dagger$ to be this unique linear transformation.
